# Html search validation android

Tags: java, android, html, forms, search

I have an android app with a search functionality. The search functionality loops through locally stored html files and appends a span with a background color to words that equal the imputed word, the same as if you press ctrl -f on your desktop. The problem i am having is that if the user searches for head, body, div, span etc it adds a span to the html tags. My question. Is there an android validation library that deals with this issue or do i need to make my own blacklist? I am aware of Android form validator's libraries but but i am not sure that they are built for what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I've use [`jsoup`](http://jsoup.org/) before to strip out unwanted html tags. You could do this in order to make the html data more "searchable". Also look at Android's [`Html.escapeHtml(CharSequence)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#escapeHtml%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) that converts html into a String.